# AWS Lambda Code in S3 Bucket not updating

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I am using cloudformation to create my lambda function with the code in a S3Bucket with versioning enabled.

```
"MYLAMBDA": {
      "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Function",
      "Properties": {
        "FunctionName": {
          "Fn::Sub": "My-Lambda-${StageName}"
        },
        "Code": {
          "S3Bucket": {
            "Fn::Sub": "${S3BucketName}"
          },
          "S3Key": {
            "Fn::Sub": "${artifact}.zip"
          },
          "S3ObjectVersion": "1e8Oasedk6sDZu6y01tioj8X._tAl3N"
        },
        "Handler": "streams.lambda_handler",
        "Runtime": "python3.6",
        "Timeout": "300",
        "MemorySize": "512",
        "Role": {
          "Fn::GetAtt": [
            "LambdaExecutionRole",
            "Arn"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

The lambda function gets created successfully. When i copy a new artifact zip file to the s3bucket, a new version of the file gets created with the new version  "S3ObjectVersion"  string. But the lambda function code is still using the older version.

The documentation of aws cloudformation clearly says the following

> To update a Lambda function whose source code is in an Amazon S3
>   bucket, you must trigger an update by updating the S3Bucket, S3Key, or
>   S3ObjectVersion property. Updating the source code alone doesn't
>   update the function.

Is there an additional trigger event, i need to create to get the code updated?

Comment: I have a similar problem, did you figure out a solution?

Comment: Same here. Sam local solves the problem at packaging time by uploading the artifact with a random name and modifying the template accordingly. Though, I can't use it because transformations are not yet supported in nested templates, and my Lambdas are nested.

Comment: I have the same issue. Can you please share the solution?

Answer (score 16):

In case anyone is running into this similar issue, I have figured out a way in my case. I use Terraform + Jenkins to create my lambda functions through s3 bucket. In the beginning, I can create the functions but it won't update once it created. I verified my zip files in s3 is updated. It took me some time to figure out that I need do one of following two changes.

solution 1: Giving a new object key when load the new zip file. In my terraform I add the git commit id as part of the s3 key.

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "lambda-abc-package" {
  bucket = "${aws_s3_bucket.abc-bucket.id}"
  key    = "${var.lambda_ecs_task_runner_bucket_key}_${var.git_commit_id}.zip"
  source = "../${var.lambda_ecs_task_runner_bucket_key}.zip"
}
```

solution 2: add source_code_hash in lambda part.

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "abc-ecs-task-runner" {
  s3_bucket         = "${var.bucket_name}"
  s3_key            = "${aws_s3_bucket_object.lambda-ecstaskrunner-package.key}"
  function_name     = "abc-ecs-task-runner"
  role              = "${aws_iam_role.AbcEcsTaskRunnerRole.arn}"
  handler           = "index.handler"
  memory_size       = "128"
  runtime           = "nodejs6.10"
  timeout           = "300"
  source_code_hash  = "${base64sha256(file("../${var.lambda_ecs_task_runner_bucket_key}.zip"))}"
```

So do either one should work. Also when checking lambda code, refresh the URL from the browser won't work. Need go back Functions and open that function again.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

I also faced the same issue , my code was in Archive.zip in S3 bucket , when I uploaded a new Archive.zip , lambda was not responding according to new code .

Solution was to again paste the link of S3 location of Archive.zip in lambda's function code section and Save it again.

**How I figured out lambda was not taking new code?**

Go to your lambda function --> Actions --> Export Function --> Download Deployment Package and check if the code is actually the code that you've recently uploaded to S3 .

Comment: This is what I have to do as well, but I'm wondering if this is expected behavior, or if it's supposed to update on its own every x amount of time, or by some other trigger.

Answer (score 2):

You have to update the S3ObjectVersion value to the new version ID in your CloudFormation template itself.

Then you have to update your Cloudformation stack with the new template.

You can do this either on the Cloudformation console or via the AWS CLI.

Comment: Do you have an example for this? This is utterly dumbfounding.

Comment: Ok, let me try again.

Comment: In the OP's example, he has `"S3ObjectVersion": "1e8Oasedk6sDZu6y01tioj8X._tAl3N"` After he has uploaded the new zip file, suppose he gets the new version `qwertyuiopasdfg2345jjQWERTY` . Now the template line needs to be updated to read `"S3ObjectVersion": "qwertyuiopasdfg2345jjQWERTY"`. Say the updated file name is **template.json** in your local directory. Well, AWS does not know about this template change, does it? So you run this command again `aws cloudformation deploy --template-file /path_to_template/template.json`. The new change will be now picked up

Comment: ok makes sense. Thanks! I actually discovered the issue to be something else in our CI pipeline but now I understand this as well. :)

Comment: @Askdesigners do share your issue as well if possible. Have a nice day!

Comment: Well basically our devops consultant built a workaround, which, in the CI deploy process would first deploy the CF template using a fixed codeURI path, and then in a second step, deploy the updated lambda code from a gulp task which ran the build, added env vars, and then ran the aws cli command to deploy the lambda directly. So sidestepping this issue completely. My issue was that in the gulp task the version was not getting incremented correctly.

Comment: Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

From AWS CLI you can do an update-function-code call like this post mentions : https://nono.ma/update-aws-lambda-function-code